# How to make a Node JS server to work only with a SPA Javascript Client provided by me?

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I have a Node JS server and a SPA Application build with JavaScript, CSS and HTML (Angular JS). 
It will be really easy to learn how everything is done on the client, because all the scripts are sent to the client, and everyone would be able to build his own client. Is there a way to make the server use only my client. Is there a way to authorize the clients?

Comment: You mean you only wanna deliver JavaScript-Files / you Angular-App to authorized Clients? Or you mean you want an Authoriztaion/Authenification System (Login, Logout) for your App?

Comment: I think he means he only wants clients using *his* web app to be able to connect to the backend rather than a third-party client, but one cannot reliably control for this. What is the specific problem with some "other" client accessing the web service?

Comment: @JoshDavidMiller Yes, this is what I meant. How to make my client and backend work only with my client if my client is SPA APP (Angular JS or other similar frameworks).

Comment: This is not reliably possible as any method you could use to "authenticate" your client could easily be included in any third-party client. But I've never seen any cases where this was necessary; why do you feel it's necessary in your project? In other words, why would you care whether or not someone was using a different front-end?

Answer (score 0):

At best you can ensure that once the client has your data, by generating a CSRF token and making sure client requests send that token back, so you can verify incoming "not the initial data" requests are properly signed.

You cannot reliably know whether a client is really running your app: using cURL [it is way too easy](http://blog.trungson.com/?p=283) to pretend to be any and all OS/browser/client/framework combinations.